# Capture C stderr from Java JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, stderr

I have a big program developed in C, and most functions have several
`fprintf(stderr, "message")` lines.

But right now I need to use those functions in a Java program. So, I implement a JNI interface to communicate between Java and C. Everything is ok, Java and C can communicate, but now I want to capture the several stderr's of C in Java... How can I do that?

Cheers ;)

Comment: +1 and starred ... but I fear the answer will be to have the C code throw the messages and then catch/print (for the C executable) and catch/throw for the JNI wrapping.

Comment: do you see the output of fprintf in java console?

Answer (score 1):

Out of my experience exactly with the same problem, i can tell that JNI bridge has very strange opinion on the importance of what's going out of JNI through standard streams. Generally it does heavy caching, spilling in unpredictable chunks and timing, and we didn't figure out how to force flushing.

We ended up with mass regex replacement of `*printf()` statements with logging to a file, done altogether on C side. Tailing the resulting logfile was way more reliable than any attempts to convince JVM that you really need the logging when C layer says so, not when JVM makes its mind on the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a JNI library, you are loading it into the JVM process, so the library STDOUT and STDERR will be the JVM STDOUT and STDERR. So the question is OS specific, and is more like "How can a process read its own STDOUT/STDERR?"

There are a couple of possibilities [Internally capture/redirect stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286918/internally-capture-redirect-stdout), but what I don't see easy is reading ONLY the STDOUT or STDERR of your library (I think that with the example I give you, once you perform the redirection you cannot go back to use console for output (*)).

As commented, the answer will depend heavily of which is your OS.

(*) I may be wrong, I am not so proficient at C/system programming.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389875/18573), I think you should be able to reassign the [processe's stderr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29). You will need another thread that reads from it while the JNI function is executing so that it does not block.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for this is to do the following, found at http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/redirect-cout-and-cerr-to-system-out-and-system-err.635861/

> The solution I came up with was to create some JNI code with two
>   methods:
>
> - one that redirect stdout to a pipe
> - one that get the output stored there
>
> Then the fow is:
>
> - call the function that redirect
> - make multiple other JNI calls
> - fetch the output and write it where I want it

The [implementation](http://www.vajhoej.dk/arne/eksperten/jniredirect/) provided from the link above looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <jni.h>

#include "Nat1.h"

#define MAXBUF 20480

static int oldstdout;
static int pipehandles[2];
static char buf[MAXBUF];

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Nat2_init(JNIEnv *cntx, jobject me)
{
    oldstdout = _dup(_fileno(stdout));
    _pipe(pipehandles,MAXBUF,_O_BINARY);
    _dup2(pipehandles[1],_fileno(stdout));
 }

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Nat2_done(JNIEnv *cntx, jobject me)
{
    int n;
    fflush(stdout);
    _dup2(oldstdout,_fileno(stdout));
    n = _read(pipehandles[0],buf,sizeof(buf));
    buf[n] = '\0';
    return (*cntx)->NewStringUTF(cntx,buf);
}
```

It is a bit cumbersome since you'd need to *start* capturing the stderr and then fetch it at a later point when you want to view it.