# Redirecting stderr stream to a file in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, stderr

Is it somehow possible to redirect the stderr to a file under MonoTouch?

In Objective-C you can do that with

```
freopen("file.log", "a+", stderr);
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619708/nslog-to-both-console-and-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286918/internally-capture-redirect-stdout).

But how can I do the same thing under MonoTouch?

The Xamarin Docs provide a section [Working with the File System](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Working_with_the_File_System) but I don't know hot to access the stderr stream from there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the .NET way using [Console.SetError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.seterror.aspx).

OTOH it's often easier to do all your writing directly into your own `TextWriter` instance.

That will allow you to *change* the destination of the error output easily between the normal `Console.Error`, a file or anything else (e.g. [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit/blob/master/NUnitLite/TouchRunner/TouchRunner.cs#L241) uses a writer that connect to a remove server socket).