# Write stderr on iPhone to both file and console

Tags: iphone, ios, stderr

I'm following the suggestion in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179108/iphone-how-to-read-application-logs-from-device) for redirecting NSLog output on an iOS device to a file, which works great.  The problem is that it no longer shows up in the console on the device.  What I'd really like is a way to tee the stderr stream to both the console and the file.  Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSLog() to both console and file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619708/nslog-to-both-console-and-file)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an acceptable answer on another thread ([NSLog() to both console and file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619708/nslog-to-both-console-and-file)).

The solution provided there is to only redirect to a file if a debugger is not detected, like this:

```
if (!isatty(STDERR_FILENO))
{
    // Redirection code
}
```

Thanks to Sailesh for that answer.

Comment: where should we write this if statement ? In the app delegate or do we have to write it in each and every view controller ?

Comment: You should write this if statement to encapsulate the code that redirects stderr to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Once you `freopen()` the file descriptor, you can read from it and do as you please with the data. Some ideas from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7286918/1224741) will be useful to you.

You could either write it back out to stdout, or try to write directly to `/dev/console`. I've never tried to open `/dev/console` on an iPhone, but I'm guessing it's possible despite being outside of the sandbox. I'm not sure how the app review process will treat it.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can redirect to a TCP socket and view on a remote telnet client. No need for XCode this way!

Basically:

1. Create a standard C function which calls an Obj-C static method:

   ```
   void tcpLogg_log(NSString* fmt, ...)
   {
       va_list args;
       va_start(args, fmt);
       [TCPLogger tcpLog:fmt :args];
       va_end(args);
   }
   ```
2. The static Obj-C method:

   ```
   (void)tcpLog:(NSString*)fmt :(va_list)args
   {
       NSLogv(fmt, args);

   if(sharedSingleton != nil && sharedSingleton.socket  != nil)
   {
     NSString *time = [sharedSingleton.dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
     NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:fmt arguments:args];
     mach_port_t tid = pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self());

     NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%X]: %@\r\n", time, tid, msg];
     NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     [sharedSingleton.socket writeData:data 
                             withTimeout:NETWORK_CLIENT_TIMEOUT_PERIOD 
                             tag:0];                                                
   }


   }
   ```
3. Then in your .pch file, add the following lines to override NSLog()

   ```
   define NSLog(...) tcpLogg_log(__VA_ARGS__); 
   void tcpLogg_log(NSString* fmt, ...);
   ```

Of course more details are required to handle the TCP Socket. Working source code is available here:
https://github.com/driedler/iOS-TCP-Logger/wiki/About